# How to get an input field when the user selects "Other" in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, antd

I'm making a form and I want the user to see an input field when they select "Others" in the dropdown.

I'm fairly new to React and was trying to get the value itself from the input field, but it's not working.

```
<FormItem>
  <h4 className={ 'register_form_title'}><span className={ "red_astrick_sign"}>*</span>Entity type</h4>
  <Select placeholder="Type of entity" onChange={value=> setFieldValue('organisation_type', Number(value))} name="organisation_attributes.organisation_type">
    <Option value="1">Public Limited Company</Option>
    <Option value="2">Private Limited Company</Option>
    <Option value="3">One Person Company</Option>
    <Option value="4">Limited Liability Partnership</Option>
    <Option value="5">Partnership Firm</Option>
    <Option value="6">Sole Proprietorship</Option>
    <Option value="0">Others</Option>
  </Select>
</FormItem>
```

This is a simple dropdown which converts the chosen value to a number, so the output of the code will be `{"organisation_type":<value>}`. But if they select "Others", the input field should determine the `<value>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a state variable to track visibility of input field.

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {show_input_field: false}
    }
```

In your onChange attribute, check if the value is 0, setState of show_input_field to true, else false, hence showing/hiding the input field.

Using the same name attribute lets you save value in the desired `'organisation_attributes.organisation_type': <value>` pair.

```
render() {
    const {show_input_field} = this.state;
    ...
    <Select placeholder="Type of entity" onChange={value => {
        setFieldValue('organisation_attributes.organisation_type', Number(value));
        if (value === 0)
            this.setState({show_input_field: true});
        else
            this.setState({show_input_field: false});
    }} name="organisation_attributes.organisation_type">
    </Select>

    {show_input_field ? <Input name="organisation_attributes.organisation_type" onChange={handleChange}/> : ""}
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can I do this in a functional component ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use state to store the current value of the drop-down and visibility of input-field.
2. Inside the `onChange` handler, only set current value with the transformation when the value is not `O`(for Others) and set input-visibility to false. But, when it is 0, set input-visibility to true.
3. Inside the `onChange` of input field, set current value as would do.